# OAuth 2.0 Authorization and Group Manager feature with Google's New Directory API for .NET library

Tags: google-oauth, google-admin-sdk, google-api-dotnet-client, google-groups-api, google-directory-api

We are currently using the "Deprecated Provisioning API" using the .NET libraries for creating Google Groups within our organization.  Provisioning API does support adding Group Members with Manager role.  As a work around, we would like to build the 'Group Manager' functionality from the 'New Directory API'  on top of the existing provisioning API.

The new feature that we want to add into existing "Provisioning API" from the "Admin SDK Directory API" is group Manager.

I have downloaded the "Google.Apis.admin.directory_v1.dll and OAuth2.0 using the .NET libraries from this link:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Apis.Admin.Directory.directory_v1/1.7.0.25-beta

I have also completed the prerequisites listed in this link:
https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/prerequisites

In order to add the 'Manager' feature to the existing provisioning API, I am trying to implement the MembersResource.InsertRequest method which is:

InsertRequest (Google.Apis.Services.IClientService service, Google.Apis.Admin.Directory.directory_v1.Data.Member body, string groupKey)

I need help in understanding the implementation for IClientService service and using OAuth2.0 authorization for authorizing requests for .NET.

I am unable to find any examples online using .NET library.  It would be extremely helpful if you share implementation examples or code snippets for using this feature.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are several samples available in our samples repository - https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/source/browse/?repo=samples.
There isn't a sample for Admin API, but there are several other samples using OAuth 2.0 for other APIs such as Drive, Tasks, Books and many others.

You should also take a look in our getting started page - https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/get_started and OAuth 2.0 - https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth.

I also published a nice blogpost with an introduction to the .NET client library for Google APIs - http://peleyal.blogspot.com/2013/09/introduction-to-google-apis-net-client.html.